# zoom issue with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jkj2yztk/7/ zoom works, but it seems to be unusable as it doesnt keep it as it should. when i zoom in, the table offsets to the left and no scroll . i have googled and searched through here and cannot seem to find any help.

```
function place(domObj, row, col) {
 domObj.classList.toggle("land");
};


$('#zoom-in').click(function() {
   updateZoom(1.0);
});

$('#zoom-out').click(function() {
   updateZoom(-1.0);
});


zoomLevel = 1;

var updateZoom = function(zoom) {
   zoomLevel += zoom;
   $('body').css({ zoom: zoomLevel, '-moz-transform': 'scale(' + zoomLevel + ')' });
}
```

is there a better way or is it an issue with my code?

Comment: another issue is you can zoom out without checking the zoom level, so `zoomLevel` can go negative which means you have to click zoom in more to actually get it to zoom. I recommend adding this line after you increment zoomLevel: `zoomLevel = zoomLevel<1?1:zoomLevel;`

Comment: Not sure what the issue is.  What does "table offsets to the left" mean?  When I open it, it's already on the left - when it gets too large the `td`s shrink, but you could some form of div + min-width.  There's a window scrollbar fine.  Tried in Chrome.

Comment: I mean that i cannot scroll any further left to get it all in. i just checked chrome and it worked ok, I think it may be with firefox.

Answer (score 0):

zoom and scale didnt transform element (position width etc.), it`s like lens. Thats why you don`t get correct scrollbars.
You need to do something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jkj2yztk/6/)

Comment: Hit zoom-in a couple times, then zoom-out. You might need to fix that :)

Comment: doing some more research, the zoom is ok, i think its the way firefox is handling it.. works ok on chrome

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev: I started working on this, did not get very far. But I did make the tile map dynamic → https://jsfiddle.net/MrPolywhirl/fqvnbg5s/